# Using Service Qualification Widget for Telecom - Error on "Find"

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-web-appbuilder, telecom

I am trying to set up the WebAppBuilder Service Qualification widget for my Group. I followed all the instructions illustrated here.
http://solutions.arcgis.com/telecommunications/help/service-qualification/get-started/configure-application/

For my layers required I have used an ArcSDE Enterprised geodatabase 10.31 layers shared as Feature Services. I used this NAServer 
http://telecom.esri.com:6080/arcgis/rest/services/BusinessServiceability/ServiceQualificationRoute/NAServer

Everything is working up to the point where I select my location and click find, then it stalls and throws these errors.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I figured out this was an issue with the browser and "Allow-control-allow-origin" extension from chrome was a fix.
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en